# How to trigger windows Print dialog from server side (asp.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing

I want to generate a PDF file on server side, and then in response want to send that file (buffer,fileName- whatever may work) and show a print dialog to ask user to print the generated PDF file.

I tried something like below. But it does not trigger window.print() dialog.

```
   public static void ForcedPrint(HttpResponse response, byte[] buffer, string fileName, string fileExtension) {
      response.Clear();
      response.Buffer=true;
      response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>");
      response.Charset="";
      response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
      response.ContentType="application/pdf";
      response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
      response.Flush();
      response.End();
    }
```

Can someone please help me with this?
The feature i am looking for is that i should be able to create PDF file on server, and in response user should get a dialog to print the generated file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to embed the PDF in the HTML document, say in a div called `thePDF` and in JavaScript code in the document, you need to invoke

```
thePDF.printWithDialog()
```

The dialog that appears will be the Adobe Reader plugin's print dialog rather than the browser's print dialog; this will allow selection of pages etc. before printing.

Comment: I didn;t get this. can you please show me some sample code, or some link for reference.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Just Google for `printWithDialog`, and you should find some useful information from the search results.

Comment: How would you embed "any file" in html ? is there a special tag for this ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you cannot generate a print command to the browser on the server. The most you can do is generate the javascript which will make it pop up with a print dialog (`window.print()`) but that wouldnt help you with what you're trying to do.

Just speculating but you may try generating a page with an iframe that points to the PDF file, and in the base page have the javascript that tells the iframe to print?

Hope this helps,

Darko