# Printning document or string using ASP.NET MVC 2 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, printing

How do I print current document or any string through printer using ASP.NET MVC 2 and C#?

Comment: On which printer? Client computer's or server?

Answer (score 1):

[How to trigger windows Print dialog from server side (asp.net)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112483/how-to-trigger-windows-print-dialog-from-server-side-asp-net)

[How can I pop-up a print dialog box using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242182/how-can-i-pop-up-a-print-dialog-box-using-javascript)

[javascript print without print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box)

[How can Print Preview be called from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230205/how-can-print-preview-be-called-from-javascript)

Comment: What would the steps be if after pressing a button, the files would have to be retrieved from the server before print dialog shows up ? Should you embed the files in html ? If so, how would you do that with ASP.NET ? if not, what's the way to do it ?